# If $x_2=a x_1$ for $a \in \mathbb{Q}$ different from -1 ,where $x_1,x_2$ are roots of $f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$, prove that $f(x)$ is reducible.

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Suppose that $f(x)$ is a polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ of degree $d>1$ with $d$ roots $x_1, \ldots, x_d$ in $\mathbb{C}$. If $x_2=a x_1$ for $a \in \mathbb{Q}$ different from -1 , prove that $f(x)$ is reducible.

This question comes from UCLA Spring 2004 Algebra Qualifying exam.

After trying induction on $n$ and failed, I tried Galois theory but cannot hit the point. Any hint or solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Edited to be more clear about the shape of the argument as suggested below)

Assume that $a\neq \pm 1$ and handle the trivial $a=0$ case separately. WLOG assume that $f(x)$ is monic.

The monic polynomials $f(x)$ and $a^{-d}f(ax)$ share the common root $x_{1}$, so their gcd (in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$) is of positive degree.

On the other hand, $a^{-d}\neq 1$, so $f(x)$ and $a^{-d}f(ax)$ have distinct constant term and thus are distinct monic polynomials of equal degree.

So the gcd of $f(x)$ and $a^{-d}f(ax)$ is a positive degree proper divisor of $f(x)$, a contradiction to $f$’s irreducibility.

Comment: You don't seem to use the assumption that $a \neq -1$, but I think it's going in the right direction.

Comment: "*the two cannot be scalar multiples of one another unless $f$ is a monomial*" $\;-\;$ Take $\,f(x)=x^2-2\,$, $\,a=-1\,$ for a counterexample.

Comment: The fact that $a\neq -1$ is used implicitly in that the values $1,a,a^{2},…$ must all be distinct for the argument to work. I suppose the $a=0$ case must be handled separately, but it’s trivial.

Comment: @Rafi You also have to handle the case $a=1$ separately. But you should [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4690299/edit) all these into the answer, not post as comments.

Comment: @Rafi : You had cut the corners a bit rough. It wasn't clear where your argument went without writing out the separate cases. I had to do it myself to be convinced.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the polynomials $f(x)$ and $f(ax)$. If $x_1,\cdots,x_d$ are the roots and $x_2 = a x_1$, let us split cases.

- If $a=0$, then $x$ divides $f(x)$, so $f$ is reducible. We are also in this case if $x_1 = 0$, so we can exclude that case moving forward.
- If $a=1$, factor $f(x)$ into irreducibles and let $m_{x_1}(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $x_1$. Since $x_2 = x_1$, the root $x_1$ has multiplicity two. The field $\mathbb Q$ is separable, so $m_{x_1}(x)^2$ divides $f(x)$, showing $f(x)$ is reducible.
- If $a \neq -1$, then the polynomials $f(x)$ and $f(ax)$ do not have the same leading coefficient. Their GCD is not $1$ since they have the root $x_1$ in common because $f(x_1) = 0$ and $f(ax_1) = f(x_2) = 0$. If their GCD is equal to $f(x)$, this means that $f(ax) = Cf(x)$ for some non-zero constant $C$. Assume $f(x)$ is irreducible and that $f(ax) = Cf(x)$. This leads to $f(0) = f(a \cdot 0) = C f(0)$, thus $C=1$ or $f(0) = 0$. In the first case (where $C=1$), by comparing the leading terms of $f(x)$ and $f(ax)$, we get $a^d = 1$, which leads to $a= \pm 1$, and those are cases we already discussed. If $f(0) = 0$, then $x$ divides $f(x)$, contradicting the irreducibility of $f(x)$ satisfying $\deg f > 1$. Since we reached a contradiction, we rollback and notice that this implies that the GCD of $f(x)$ and $f(ax)$ is not $f(x)$. It wasn't constant either, so it's some divisor of $f(x)$, showing it is reducible.

Hope that helps,

Comment: (+1) $\,$ The case $a=1$ could also be argued with $\deg \gcd(f, f') \ge 1$.

Comment: @dxiv It was kind of an easy case to be honest, I just took whatever first argument I could come up with. Proving a polynomial with a double root is reducible in characteristic zero... Thanks for the +1 though!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f(x)$ irreducible and let $K$ be its splitting field.
Let $\alpha$ and $\beta\in K$ two roots of $f(X)$. Then $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$ are isomorphic subextension of $K$ and if
$$\varphi:\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)\longrightarrow\mathbb{Q}(\beta)
$$
is the isomorphism we must have $\varphi(\alpha)=\beta$

The isomorphism $\varphi$ extends to an embedding
$$
\phi:K\rightarrow\overline{\mathbb{Q}}
$$
and since $K$ is normal in fact $\phi\in{\rm Aut}(K)$.
But the latter set is a finite group so that if $\beta=a\alpha$ with
$\pm1\neq a\in\mathbb{Q}$ we get a contradiction because $\phi$ must have finite order.

Comment: I was trying to find that proof! So basically, if $\varphi$ fixes $\mathbb Q$, it maps roots of $f(x)$ to themselves. And if it maps $\alpha$ to $a \alpha$, it maps $\beta = a \alpha$ to 
$$
\varphi(a \alpha) = \varphi(a) \varphi(\alpha) = a (a \alpha) = a^2 \alpha,
$$
which then also has to be a root. I guess that's the argument in the end? You don't even need Galois theory of fields or anything, just the fact that $f(x)$ has finitely many roots, and therefore $a^{d!} \alpha = \alpha$, so $a^{d!} = 1$, and $a = \pm 1$. (I took $d!$ since $\varphi$ generates a cyclic subgroup of $S_d$.)

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Well, you need to know that a splitting field is normal and that for normal extensions ${\rm Hom}(K,\overline{\mathbb{Q}})={\rm Aut}(K)$ which is a finite group.

Comment: why wouldn't it suffice to know that $f(x)$ has finitely many roots? Can't we deduce $a^n \alpha = \alpha$ just from the fact that $f$ has finitely many roots and use the pigeonhole principle with that? We don't need to know anything about where the automorphism lives I think. I'm curious why you though that knowledge of the splitting field was required.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: If $\varphi$ is not an automorphism what sense do you give to $\varphi^2$?

Comment: I understand finding $\varphi : \mathbb Q(\alpha) \to \mathbb Q(\beta)$, but since $\beta = a \alpha$ and $a$ cannot be zero ($f$ irreducible), we have $\mathbb Q(\alpha) = \mathbb Q(\beta)$. 

You don't need to consider $\varphi \in \mathrm{Aut}(K)$, you just need $\varphi \in \mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb Q(\alpha))$. As soon as you have this with $\varphi(\alpha) = a \alpha = \beta$, you can say that $0 = \varphi(f(\alpha)) = f(\varphi(\alpha))$, and then recursively show that $\varphi^n(\alpha)$ is a root of $f$ for all $n \ge 0$ by saying $f(\varphi^n(\alpha)) = \varphi^n(f(\alpha)) = 0$.